# ¿Cómo hacer con php que cargue en la pagina documentos sólo cuando hago click para descargarlo?

Tags: php

Como comento en el título, tengo la duda de si alguien conoce alguna forma con php para que se realice la descarga de un documento sólo cuando hago click en un botón de descargar.

Para poner en contexto, tengo una vista que muestra registros de alumnos que han subido ejercicios (documentos) para su corrección, y en donde hay un botón al lado de cada registro de descargar para poder ver el archivo que han subido. Cuando son pocos documentos no hay problema pero, cuando son muchos relentiza considerablemente la carga de la pagina web. Por ello mi pregunta de si hay alguna forma con php de agilizar ese procedimiento.

Muestro cual es mi código actual para la búsqueda de los archivos y su descarga:

```
<?php 
$f = 'documentosAlum/' . md5('XXX' . $entregaTarea->id);

if($fileOrigen = glob($f . '.*')) {  
   
     $fileOrigen = $fileOrigen[0];
     $fileDestino = 'descargaAdmin/'
      . $entregaTarea->nombre . ' '
      . $entregaTarea->apellido1 . ' ' 
      . $entregaTarea->apellido2 . '-'  
      . str_replace($f, '', $fileOrigen);
                                            
      copy($fileOrigen, $fileDestino); 
 ?>

 <a href="<?php echo '/' . $fileDestino ; ?>" download="">Descargar</a>
```

Comment: De cuantos registros por query estamos hablando? Es lentitud de la query? Los archivos están en la DB o solo la URL para descargar?? Yo he hecho algo similar a lo tuyo y no he tenido problemas con lentitud.

Comment: En algunos casos estamos hablando de cientos de registros, y cada registro con su correspondiente documento, haciendo que tarde incluso 20 segundos hasta terminar de cargar la pagina. Estuve haciendo comprobaciones de cuanto tardaba en ejecutarse cada registro del foreach ($entregaTareas as $entregaTarea), antes y después de buscar el archivo, y la relentización se produce cuando busca el documento. Por eso preguntaba si hay alguna forma de hacer que vaya más rápido o que se realice la búsqueda del documento que se quiera sólo cuando se haga la descarga. Los archivos están en una carpeta.

Comment: Cientos de registros no van a tardar ese tiempo. En la query debe venir la URL desde la DB, así que no creo que sea la cantidad de registros. Cuando dices que el lag se produce **cuando busca el documento** te refieres a la misma query? Por otro lado el código que pones en la pregunta es que hace exactamente?? Así en palabras sencillas...

Comment: No estoy seguro de cómo usas `glob()`. ¿Por qué copias el archivo en lugar de ligarlo al original?.

Comment: Ya, por eso me extraña que tarde tanto tiempo. 

El archivo cuando lo sube el alumno, se sube con un md5 para cifrarlo y está asociado a una id a la carpeta documentosAlum. Entonces con la id que se subió utilizo glob() para buscarlo en la carpeta documentosAlum. Como el archivo quiero descargarlo con los datos del alumno (nombre,apellidos, etc) lo copio y lo guardo en la carpeta descargaAdmin, de manera que sigo teniendo el original y la copia con el nombre que quiero. Ese archivo es el que descargo.

Cuando digo buscar el documento, me refiero a partir de que se realiza el glob().

Comment: El nombre del archivo descargado lo puedes asignar en el atributo `download` de la liga, independientemente del nombre del archivo original.